# Passing parameters in docker-compose and into POM

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

I know there is a way to pass parameters in maven through the POM.

**POM MAVEN**

```
<properties>
    <webproperty> ${webproperty} </webproperty>
</properties>
```

**COMMAND LINE WITH MAVEN**

```
mvn install "-Dwebproperty=chrome"
```

I recently switched over to Docker and I was wondering if there was still a way to pass the parameters through the POM? I was looking at some examples and was wondering if I was going about it the right way.

**Docker YAML**

```
 build:
    image: something/webtest 
    environment:
     - HUB_HOST=hub
    browser:
     - BROWSER=${BROWSER_TYPE}
```

**COMMAND LINE WITH DOCKER**

```
docker-compose up BROWSER_TYPE=chrome
```

Also will this command still work.

```
System.getProperty("BROWSER_TYPE");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The pom's parameters can not be passed in out side of pom xml. I think you can use a template file to generate each pom file seperately.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

1. Add an argument in the DockerFile.

> ```
> ARG BROWSER
> ```

2. create the command in your jenkinsfile

> ```
> BROWSER=chrome docker-compose up myrun
> ```

3. In the docker yaml file add it to the build

> environment:
>
> - HUB_HOST=hub
> - browser= ${BROWSER}

4. Add it to the java command

> ```
> -Dbrowser="$browser"
> ```

5. Use System.getProperty("browser") to call it in your code.